# Multi-mode resource-constrained project scheduling pb. - optimalization

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-optimization

I would like to make code in java for scheduling project, where every task have dependency on another task and also have several possibilities for resource and time completion.

This is called Multi-mode resource-constrained project scheduling problem but I cant find any good information about it? Can someone give me some clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best language for such a project might in fact be Prolog. Have a look at [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/). It is a widely used tool for Constraint Logic Programming written in Prolog. It has bindings for Java too.

There is a book: [A Gentle Guide to Constraint Logic Programming via ECLiPSe](http://www.anclp.pl/) about it that mentions various kinds of scheduling and resource allocation problems. Maybe you could get at least some inspiration there.

[2023 Sánchez et al. - Resource-constrained multi-project scheduling problem: A survey](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221722007639)

If you want more information about the problem itself then I recommend using [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Multi-mode%20resource-constrained%20scheduling). A brief search returns:

- [A genetic algorithm for multi-mode resource constrained project scheduling problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221796001804)
- [Multi-mode resource-constrained project scheduling by a simple, general and powerful sequencing algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221797003482)
- [PSPLIB - A project scheduling problem library ☆: OR Software - ORSEP Operations Research Software Exchange Program](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221796001701)

If you go through the references of these articles then you will very likely find more suitable study material.

Comment: A guide related to this topic: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2022.09.033. Despite this survey being just for multi-project RCMPSP, it is possible to learn and understand various definitions and ideas related to the single problem RCPSP.